# How to display a certain view depending on random number generation in swift?

Tags: swift, match, view

I am following a tutorial, this is the repo on [git](https://github.com/learn-co-students/swift-viewLifeCycle-lab-swift-intro-000)

I have 7 views, that represent the die. And 6 labels, that show the random number each time I press the dieButtonTapped() button. When I press the button, first label appears with the random number generated, which is good, but I can't get the appropriate view to show up. So, if the random number is 5, label shows up with the number 5 in it, and 5 views out of 7 should show up, representing the die.
What it is doing now is that it shows random views that do not match the random number showed on the label.

Please help me correct `func rearrangeDie()` function to match what `func updateScore(roll: Int)` is returning.

Thank you !
Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view3: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view4: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view5: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view6: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view7: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label5: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label6: UILabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view1.isHidden = true
        view2.isHidden = true
        view3.isHidden = true
        view4.isHidden = true
        view5.isHidden = true
        view6.isHidden = true
        view7.isHidden = true

        label1.isHidden = true
        label2.isHidden = true
        label3.isHidden = true
        label4.isHidden = true
        label5.isHidden = true
        label6.isHidden = true

    }

    @IBAction func dieButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        rearrangeDie()
        updateScore(roll: randomDiceRoll())
    }

    // Returns back a random Int (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6)
    func randomDiceRoll() -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)

    }

    func rearrangeDie() {

        if randomDiceRoll() == 1 {
            view7.isHidden = false
        }
        else if randomDiceRoll() == 2 {
            view2.isHidden = false
            view5.isHidden = false
        }
        else if randomDiceRoll() == 3 {
            view2.isHidden = false
            view7.isHidden = false
            view5.isHidden = false
        }
        else if randomDiceRoll() == 4 {
            view1.isHidden = false
            view2.isHidden = false
            view5.isHidden = false
            view6.isHidden = false
        }
        else if randomDiceRoll() == 5 {
            view1.isHidden = false
            view2.isHidden = false
            view5.isHidden = false
            view6.isHidden = false
            view7.isHidden = false
        }
        else if randomDiceRoll() == 6 {
            view1.isHidden = false
            view2.isHidden = false
            view3.isHidden = false
            view4.isHidden = false
            view5.isHidden = false
            view6.isHidden = false
        }


    }


    func updateScore(roll: Int) {

        let diceScore = String(roll)

        if label1.isHidden {
            label1.text = diceScore
            label1.isHidden = false

        }
        else if label2.isHidden {
            label2.text = diceScore
            label2.isHidden = false

        }
        else if label3.isHidden {
            label3.text = diceScore
            label3.isHidden = false

        }
        else if label4.isHidden {
            label4.text = diceScore
            label4.isHidden = false

        }
        else if label5.isHidden {
            label5.text = diceScore
            label5.isHidden = false

        }
        else if label6.isHidden {
            label6.text = diceScore
            label6.isHidden = false

        }
        else {
            viewDidLoad()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please look into IBOutletCollections, it will save you so much setup code here.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically generating a new random number each time you call `randomDiceRoll()`. Store it in a variable and access it throughout the if statements.

I would also strongly suggest a programatically created layout and a serious refactoring.

```
func rearrangeDie() {
    let randomDiceRoll = randomDiceRoll()

    if randomDiceRoll == 1 {
        view7.isHidden = false
    }
    else if randomDiceRoll == 2 {
        view2.isHidden = false
        view5.isHidden = false
    }
    else if randomDiceRoll == 3 {
        view2.isHidden = false
        view7.isHidden = false
        view5.isHidden = false
    }
    else if randomDiceRoll == 4 {
        view1.isHidden = false
        view2.isHidden = false
        view5.isHidden = false
        view6.isHidden = false
    }
    else if randomDiceRoll == 5 {
        view1.isHidden = false
        view2.isHidden = false
        view5.isHidden = false
        view6.isHidden = false
        view7.isHidden = false
    }
    else if randomDiceRoll == 6 {
        view1.isHidden = false
        view2.isHidden = false
        view3.isHidden = false
        view4.isHidden = false
        view5.isHidden = false
        view6.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem :( It still does not match the labels that indicate random numbers from this function `func updateScore(roll: Int)`

Answer (score 0):

@the4Kman is correct in stating that calling the `randomDiceRoll()` will generate a new random number every time which leads to the problem you are facing. What you need instead, is to merge your `rearrangeDie()` and `updateScore()` methods into one. Also, as @nanothread59 suggested, you should use `IBOutletCollections`.

You should declare your `collections` like this

```
//Notice that you cannot make them "weak" properties
@IBOutlet var views: Array<UIView>!
@IBOutlet var labels: Array<UILabel>!
```

Then give each of your `view` and `label` a tag from 1-7 in storyboard and connect them to their respective `outletCollections`. Once it is setup, you can merge your methods into one like this

```
func update() {
    //Hide all Views and Labels
    for item in views {
        item.isHidden = true
    }
    for item in labels {
        item.isHidden = true
    }

    //Get Random Value
    let random = randomDiceRoll()

    //UPDATE YOUR VIEWS' AND LABELS' HIDDEN PROPERTY AND VALUES HERE BASED ON THE RANDOM VALUE

    //To access a particular view or label, you'll do something like this
    for item in views {
        if item.tag == {whatever} {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
    //Repeat the above loop for labels as well
}
```

P.S. With `IBOutletCollections`, your `viewDidLoad` will also change like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Hide all Views and Labels
    for item in views {
        item.isHidden = true
    }
    for item in labels {
        item.isHidden = true
    }
}
```